# Make a list based on marker in vector

Tags: r

Often I'm faced with a vector like this:

```
 [1] "C" ""  "A" "C" "D" "A" "I" "B" "H" "I" ""  "C" "E"
[14] "H" "J" "J" "E" "A" ""  "I" "I" "I" "G" ""  "F"
```

Where there is some kind of marker/indicator that I want to use to break the vector up into a list of vectors like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "C"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "C" "D" "A" "I" "B" "H" "I"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "E" "H" "J" "J" "E" "A"

[[4]]
[1] "I" "I" "I" "G"

[[5]]
[1] "F"
```

In this case the marker is an empty string `""`.  I can do this but am wondering if there's a faster more efficient way to achieve this.  It seems I should be able to use `split` for this but can't think of how in a simple way.  Here is my current approach:

```
## MWE
set.seed(15)
x <- sample(c("", LETTERS[1:10]), 25, TRUE, prob=c(.2, rep(.08, 10)))

locs <- which(x == "")
start <- c(1, locs + 1)
end <- c(locs - 1, length(x))

lapply(Map(":", start, end), function(ind){
    x[ind]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this. First, the test data

```
a<-c("C","","A","C","D","A","I","B",
    "H","I","","C","E","H","J","J",
    "E","A","","I","I","I","G","","F")
```

Now we find all the sentinal values

```
breaks <- a==""
```

And now we use split and assign each value to a new list when we encounter a break

```
split(a[!breaks], cumsum(breaks)[!breaks])
```

and that returns

```
$`0`
[1] "C"

$`1`
[1] "A" "C" "D" "A" "I" "B" "H" "I"

$`2`
[1] "C" "E" "H" "J" "J" "E" "A"

$`3`
[1] "I" "I" "I" "G"

$`4`
[1] "F"
```

as desired.

Because we use the value of `breaks` so often in the `split`, it's normally hard to write as a one-liner. That's why i like to use a helper function called [withX()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/35ff2265619762d49159) which I would use like

```
withX(a=="", split(a[!X], cumsum(X)[!X]))
```

Comment: Oh the beauty.  +1 I think this is the winner.  I'll give it a bit before the green check.  Nice approach.

Comment: I do end up using `withX` quite a bit. It's nice to be able to play with an object without having to assign it some variable you really don't care about. I always liked how `with` makes it easy to play with data.frame columns, i just wanted something to make it easier to play with other objects in a similar way. I'm not sure i picked the best name yet, so if you have better suggestions, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach

```
 tapply(x,cumsum(!nchar(x)), function(x) if(length(x)>1) tail(x,-1L) else x)
```